# Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing Perhaps you forgot to surroundsuch ..as: node on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Error Message

> [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
>
> [Pipeline] sh [Pipeline]
>
> End of Pipeline
>
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException:
>   Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing Perhaps you forgot
>   to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node

My file Android SDK path on my Mac

> /Users/bhanukaisuru/Library/Android/sdk

I also download android sdk tool only. Path is:

> /Users/bhanukaisuru/Library

Environment Variable
Config Jenkins > Configure System
**Name: ANDROID_HOME**
**Value: /Users/don/Library**

Full Pipeline *// I commented above code, because of for check the issue*

```
def home = sh(script: "echo $ANDROID_HOME",returnStdout: true).trim()

//         def SDKPath = "$home/Android/sdk"
//         stage("Preparing SDK"){
//             // Check SDK Downloaded
//             def isSDKDownloaded = sh(script: "test -e sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip && echo true || echo false",returnStdout: true).trim()
//             if(isSDKDownloaded == "false"){
//                 // Download SDK
//                 sh "wget 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip'"
//             }
//             // Check if SDK is Extracted
//             def isExtracted = sh(script: "test -e $SDKPath/tools && echo true || echo false",returnStdout: true).trim()
//             if(isExtracted == "false"){
//                 sh "mkdir -p $SDKPath"
//                 //Unzip SDK
//                 sh "unzip sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -d $SDKPath"
//             }
// // Install SDK Tools
//             sh "yes | $SDKPath/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'build-tools;28.0.3' 'platform-tools' 'platforms;android-27'"
// sh "ls $SDKPath/licenses"
//             // See installed And Available SDK
//             sh "$SDKPath/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list"
//             // Accept All SDK Licences
//             sh "yes | $SDKPath/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses"
//         }

// def selectedBranch = SELECTED_RELEASE_BRANCH
//          stage('Checkout') {
//              git branch: selectedBranch, url: 'git@gitlab.com:app/wtc.git'
//             // Remove Existing local properties
//             sh 'rm local.properties ||:'
//             // Write sdk.dir Path into local properties file
//             sh "echo 'sdk.dir=$SDKPath' >> local.properties"
//          }

//          stage('Setup Tools') {
//              withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'android_keystore', variable: 'KEYFILE')]) {
//                  sh "cp \$KEYFILE app/key.jks"
//              }   
//          }

//          stage('Build Release APK') {
//              sh "./gradlew clean assembleRelease"
//          }

//          stage('Upload to Play Store') {
//             androidApkUpload googleCredentialsId: 'p12 key from GCP', apkFilesPattern: '**/*-release.apk', trackName: 'alpha'
//          }

//          stage('Cleanup Credential') {
//              sh "rm app/key.jks"
//          }
```

I printed path: It's printed

```
echo "$ANDROID_HOME"
```

output is :

> echo
>   /Users/bhanukaisuru/Library

Answer (score 0):

now, It's working. Is there any way to fix the above issue. please let me kow

```
node('master') {
//Existing same code
}
```